# How can I further improve my question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-closed

[Initializing PHP classes in the Web server/browser context](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13829402/443219)

I asked this question with very [vague language](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/764aa9d7-6b75-4124-8e0f-911c20105105/view-source) a few days ago. I myself had a hard time understanding what the problem was, so it ended up like a wall of text with very little value. I am sorry for the waste of time caused.

I have now edited the question with further details, and I also solved my problem which I'd like to write as an answer. What can I do to further improve my question and have it re-opened?

Here's a summary of the solution I intend to post, once reopened:

> I have now understood how to use Composer's autoloader to my benefit, and I am using Composer for getting everything I need into the app's directory. I am also using the same autoloader to get to my own classes in bootstrap.php, by following the PSR-0 convention.
>
> index.php now has a single call to bootstrap.php for getting everything in place, then I directly start using my core class ExportExcel's functions through Symfony's service container and finish the export.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Best practices", "common approach"

These parts of your question scare me a bit.  It's not something that can be answered concretely, despite that you use a lot of concrete technology.  It's also the case that you haven't shown what you've tried, or where you're stuck - you're looking for the "best" way to go about the problem.

That's a bit tricky to answer in its current form.  I wouldn't be giving a reopen vote to this until it got to be more concrete.

Comment: Thank you for reading. I did not claim to be using 'best practices', I just would like to point out why I am doing what I am trying. I actually do have a concrete answer now, too, especially taking off on the answers I already got. When I posted that question I couldn't even start scripting because the problem was nebulous to me, now it is not.

Comment: So as a demonstration of improvement, perhaps you should also share where each component lives to further demonstrate your point?

Comment: Thanks, I have added this information to this question...

Comment: Thanks for your help in reopening. I could post my answer to the question. Good day!